# Read file txt into list 2 Dimension in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to ask something about python here. I'm new in this kind of programming

**Input :**

```
Emma,F,19414
Olivia,F,19246
Ava,F,16237
```

**Output :**

```
[['Emma', 'F', '19414'], 
 ['Olivia', 'F', '19246'],
 ['Ava', 'F', '16237']]
```

So that's what I want to get working. It's a 2D list, so i could access the column which value is 'F' in the row 1 with `theList[0][1]`

Comment: how you are giving input? is it a plain string as input? or your input is read from file?

Comment: Where is your programcode?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: its is answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f.txt:

```
Emma,F,19414
Olivia,F,19246
Ava,F,16237
Emma,DF,19414
Olivia,D,19246
```

Code:

```
with open("path/to/f.txt", "r") as fp:
    f_content = fp.read().strip() # read lines and strip whitespaces
print([x for x in [i.split(',') for i in f_content.split("\n")] if x[1] =="F"]) # prints only list if column is F
```

Answer (score 0):

If input is a simple multiline string, let us say then:

```
s_input = """Emma,F,19414
Olivia,F,19246
Ava,F,16237"""

theList = [ each.split(",") for each in s_input.splitlines() ]
print theList

for i, _ in enumerate(theList):
    print theList[i][1]
```

Output could be:

```
[['Emma', 'F', '19414'], ['Olivia', 'F', '19246'], ['Ava', 'F', '16237']]
F
F
F
```

Comment: @ANJAYCHANNEL, welcome. please upvote if you like answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

**infile.txt**

```
Emma,F,19414
Olivia,F,19246
Ava,F,16237
```

**Code :**

```
list_of_lists = []
with open('infile.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split(',')]
    # in alternative, if you need to use the file content as numbers
    # inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',')]
    list_of_lists.append(inner_list)

print(list_of_lists)
```

**Output :**

```
[['Emma', 'F', '19414'], ['Olivia', 'F', '19246'], ['Ava', 'F', '16237']]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: @ANJAY.  Welcome. :)